# Equivalent JQuery for Javascript id passing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know the javascript to pass id when an event is triggered as below

```
<td><a id="applyChange_${(loop.index)}" onclick="javascript:applyChange(this);">

function applyChange(obj){
   console.log(obj.id;) // this returns the id of the element
}
```

But how, the same can be written in jQuery?

Comment: Yes. `$('elementId').click(function() { console.log(this.id); });`

Comment: This is a very basic thing to do in jQuery, so I would recommend looking up a [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/)

Comment: One thing i am re-mentioning here, i am passing dynamic id as "applyChange_${(loop.index)}". here "${(loop.index)}" is dynamic, this is not static. so i dont know the exact id when .click event is taken place. Hence above comment may not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add class** to your `a` tags and **remove inline event binder**

```
<td><a id="applyChange_${(loop.index)}" class="applyChange">
```

With this structure you can write **Jquery selectors on classes**, And on click of any element with the class `applyChange` you can gets that particular clicked elements `id` by using `$(this).attr('id')`

So the script would be like

```
$('.applyChange').on('click',function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this if you just want to get the index:

```
<a class="applyChange" data-id="${(loop.index)}">
```

then setup the click event when the page loads (assuming these are dynamically created)

```
$(document).on('click', '.applyChange', function () { console.log($(this).data('id')) });
```